# Best practises to save many large images in Java Spring in 2022

Tags: java, spring-boot, file-upload

I want to save a large amount of images on a server from mobile upload in Java for face recognition, probably like 5-10 image of 5 Mb size on average with large time gaps inbetween. I use several docker container for the java backend which run the image processing pipeline, face detection and face recognition with each have around 8 Mb RAM.

The user is expected to label the uploaded images right away after the upload, in case the face identification did not work. Thus, every uploaded image should run as fast as possible through the image processing pipeline.

First, consider the frontend upload view with thymeleaf where the image are uploaded as JPEG and PNG mainly

```
<body>
    <form style="">
      <input type="file" id="files" multiple method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" th:action="@{/uploadImage}"/><br/>
      <output id="selectedFiles"></output>
      <input id="uploadButton" type="button" value="Upload" style=""/>
    </form>  
</body>
```

Secondly, the loading of multiple images into memory with the help of a corresponding model uploadedFile for multiple Multipart files and saving them on the local file system on the server:

```
@RequestMapping("/saveImage")
    public void saveFile(HttpServletRequest servletRequest,
            @ModelAttribute UploadedFile uploadedFile,
            BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
 
        MultipartFile multipartFile = uploadedFile.getMultipartFile();
        String fileName = multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();
        try {
            File file = new File(servletRequest.getServletContext().getRealPath("/"), fileName);
            multipartFile.transferTo(file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

My first question is if it is still best practise to save the images temporally first in the local file system on the server before further processing or should the images be directly stored in the db?

Secondly, would it make sense to have another docker container only for image processing, ie checking if a certain path is not empty and firing up the image processing pipeline on itself?

Thank you for any tip towards one or the other direction!

Comment: code paste is broken. notice the syntax highlighting. please take the [tour], then [edit] your question to fix it.

Comment: It is best to get your application working first - then you can focus on whether / what you might want to change if there are performance problems. It's hard to give guidance from this code sample and lack of information on the server, client, types of discs or memory limitations, method (and limitation / cost) of the upload.

Comment: Still difficult to answer. In your case consider: Does you server have enough memory to run without saving images locally? What format does the image recognition app use? Will performance be OK if saving to files first? Does your user agreement allow you to save locally? Would the user be upset if the upload crashed near the end and they had to start from beginning, compared to resume from last successful upload?

Comment: I know. I am having trouble breaking the problem down because there are so many unknows but the writing and your previous comments already help me to see it clearer, so thank you!